# stream_set_blocking() always returning false for files on windows

Tags: php, io

I am trying to read (or write) in files in a non blocking way. While stream_set_blocking() works perfectly with linux, i didn't manage to make it work on windows.

Am I doing something wrong, is this a bug, or just windows behavior?

Is there any alternative?

```
$fileRes = fopen("foo.txt", 'wb');
if ($fileRes === false) {
    throw new Exception();
}
var_dump(stream_set_blocking($fileRes, 0));
```

--> This always return false on windows...

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: bughttps://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75538

At the current stage, even if the non-blocking flag can be changed on some platforms, it doesn't guarantee non-blocking with the regard to possible obstacles.